# How can I add index, and reindex to the existing attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing

I'm fetching a record by the code just like these

```
@community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_name])
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

I want to make it faster loading, so I'm thinking of adding index to them just like this.
If I do `rake db:migrate`, does it reindex to the existing records also?
Or just the records that will be created from now on?
Do it improve the speed of loading by adding index just like this?

```
class AddIndexToCommunity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :communities, [:community_name, :title, :body], :name=>:communities_idx
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :communities, [:community_name, :title, :body], :name=>:communities_idx
  end
end



class AddIndexToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :users, [:username, :nickname, :body], :name=>:users_idx
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :users, [:username, :nickname, :body], :name=>:users_idx
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake db:migrate` will perform database migrations and apply indeces immediately.You should apply indeces only to columns which you use in searching. Remember that indeces add time penalty on `insert` and `update` operations. If you load records on by their `names`, add indeces only to `names`:

```
class AddIndexToCommunity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :communities, :community_name
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :communities, :community_name
  end
end



class AddIndexToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :users, :username
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :users, :username
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise:) what if I'm using sunspot search? sunspot indeces its own index to the attributes that I've chosen. For example, I added 'title' attribute to sunspot search. However, it is not indexed in MySQL. It seems, sunspot is doing something on its own.

Comment: If you are planning to search for text (or multiple columns at the same time with complex logic) use full-text search engines. Solr is a very good solution. Yes, Solr will build its own indeces.

Comment: I've already implemented full-text search with Solr. So I don't wanna touch that. It's working fine. I just don't see those attributes in index list on MySQL.  But it's supposed to be okay, right?  So now I just decided to add index to `community_name` and `username`. Thanks:)

Comment: one more question, please. In sunspot search, I have to do `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`.  But I don't need to do that kind of reindex thing if I'm doing `rake db:migrate` it just does all even to the existing records. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry last question! if there are 2 tables such as `tags` and `taggings`, and `taggings` has `tag_id` attributes. Should I add index to  `tag.name` and `tagging.tag_id` because it fetches records related tag faster?

Comment: Yes, of course. Solr will reindex according the rules in your model.

Comment: I think you should add both indeces.